# Find if a Property is Valid inside JavaScript Array of Objects

Tags: javascript

I have a collection of Customer objects inside the JavaScript Array.

```
var customer = Customer(); 
customer.firstName = "John"; 
customer.isEnabled = true 

var customer2 = Customer(); 
customer2.firstName = "Mary"; 
customer2.isEnabled = false

var customers = [customer,customer2];
```

Now, I want to return true if any of the objects inside the customers array property "isEnabled" = false. Basically I want a way to validate a property of every object that is inside the array (customers).

**UPDATE:**

So using the some function I can do something like this:

```
customers.some(e => e.isEnabled == true)
```

So, now it will only return true if all the elements in the array have isEnabled property to true. Is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Here is how you'd use it in your case:

```
var customers = [
    { firstName: "John", isEnabled: true },
    { firstName: "Mary", isEnabled: false },
];

var goodCustomers = [
    { firstName: "George", isEnabled: true },
    { firstName: "Sandra", isEnabled: true },
];

function isNotEnabled(customer) {
    return !customer.isEnabled;
}
function isEnabled(customer) {
    return customer.isEnabled;
}

customers.some(isNotEnabled);
//=> true
goodCustomers.some(isNotEnabled);
//=> false

customers.every(isEnabled);
//=> false
goodCustomers.every(isEnabled);
//=> true
```

Functional libraries are also excellent for this kind of problem, here's a [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/) example just for fun:

```
R.all(R.prop("isEnabled"), customers);
//=> false
R.any(R.compose(R.not, R.prop("isEnabled")), customers);
//=> true
```

Comment: Basically it should only return true if all the items with their property isEnabled is true in the array.

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood you a bit, included another example with [].every()

Comment: Thanks! I think I worded my question poorly. Sorry for that. every() is awesome!

Comment: You're welcome. Also the *lodash* advice isn't bad per se, even though it's a bit overkill for your problem, it allows you to use that kind of programming style in a lot of other scenarios (and it'd be more elegant). There's Ramda also.

Answer (score 0):

Use `every` method:

```
customers.every(function(v){ return v.isEnabled;  }); // will return true if every object 'is enabled'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Underscore.js, You could use _.where() function.

```
_.where(customers, {isEnabled: true});
```

Answer (score -2):

Checkout the [lodash](https://lodash.com/) library. It has lots of such functions already written for you.